# Slow dropdown menu transition CSS

Tags: html, css

I've created a dropdown menu in a [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Relborg/Kpxpf/11/).

I want to have a slow transition of the dropdown menus.

Right now it just pops out and it looks quite bland that way.

```
// Ignore this line
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should use this example as a base for yours

I also recommend using the  tag instead of just a regular  with an id of main-nav-menu.

And you are using a background image to create a blue background? You can just give the li and a elements a color in css to achieve what you want instead of using background image.

Here is the code you should use: http://www.newmediacampaigns.com/blog/nicer-navigation-with-css-transitions-part-2

Here is what each one looks like: http://codepen.io/toddsynan/full/pJuyx

The following is what the guy uses to create the transition when the max-height changes from 0 to 150px by hovering.

```
 -webkit-transition:max-height 500ms ease;
 -moz-transition:max-height 500ms ease;
 -o-transition:max-height 500ms ease;
 transition:max-height 500ms ease;
```